# Good name for a list variable in java

Tags: java, naming-conventions

What of the following is used popularly or is the standard :

```
private List<String> names ;
```

**OR**

```
private List<String> listOfNames ;
```

**OR**

```
private List<String> namesList ;
```

Comment: This is not really a question...if you want naming conventions, then look them up really.

Comment: Don't downvote this, this is a valid question. A bit simple and easily resolved, sure, but still a valid question.

Comment: This is likely to solicit debate and opinion.

Comment: Chapter 11 of the book [Code Complete](http://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670) is dedicated to variables naming. You could get good ideas from it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once upon a time we had Hungarian notation, because IDEs didn't provide intellisense and programmers were too dumb to realise that having a 30,000 line long block of code was unreadable*. Nowadays IDEs are friendly, programmers have started using small, neat classes, we have JavaDoc and things in genral are easier to read.

So, just name your variable for its usage. i.e. names. I'm no fan of pre/post-fixing variables as it often makes them harder to understand.

(*) i.e. Me, there's probably some deeply shameful code out there with my name on it.

Answer (score 9):

Depends on the use case.

```
names
```

If this is the only "names" variable

```
namesList
```

If therr are other names collestions (e.g. namesSet) in your code.

```
private List<String> listOfNames
```

Is wrong; if you will be so specific you should write listOfStrings or

```
private List<Name> listOfNames
```

redefine your type (whatever Name is).

Comment: If I was forced to have both a list and set of names, I'd use `names` for the list, and `nameSet` for the set since the type implies plurality already. Not that I think about stuff like this or am putting off work or anything.

Comment: Of course, YOU will remember that names is the List and not the Set. But will remember code readers too ? Anyway, it is a question of style and (team) conventions.

Answer (score 1):

The conventional name will be `namesList`.

PS : If you use auto complete in Eclipse you'll see that.!

Comment: How is that "conventional"? I wouldn't call it that. What if you changed the type to something other than a list, or it was declared as a `Collection`? Repeating type information in a name is brittle and verbose.

Comment: OK you're right.!
Its "Conventional" just For me.! :)

Comment: It is not `conventional`, and even more, if to check `Clean code`- one or recommendations is to avoid using of types in names, it is senseless. We are not calling the `firstName` of `User` as `firstNameString`. So - `names` is cool there and in all such cases, using of type is bad practice

Answer (score 1):

Regarding variable name, you can use anything.

***My team says*** *after reading variable name, one should understand what that variable will hold data BUT variable name should be as per Java naming convention*.

***In your case I would go with `listOfNames`, because it will say the variable is of type list and it has names.***

### Also read [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

Comment: But you already know the type--and the type might change; why force a corresponding variable name change? Also, the conventions you link to don't indicate that Systems Hungarian notation is conventional--otherwise wouldn't something like `myWidth` be `floatMyWidth` or `myWidthFloat`? Communicating type in a variable name is *far* less important than communicating intent, which `names` does just fine.

Comment: @DaveNewton : For you `names` is just fine.. For me, `listOfNames` is best.

Comment: I understand that--it just contradicts the link you provide as a reference (and causes extra work).

Answer (score -1):

whatever is suitable for you and your team go with that.

IDEs are very smart they will take for everything else like what a given name stands for, type, permissions etc.